# Moving Jetpack buttons to appear below the first H2 title on all project/post pages

Tags: plugins, css, plugin-jetpack

I would like to know, how can I move the Jetpack sharing buttons appearing under the H1 title, to appear below the first H2 title, on all project and post pages I have.
Here is a URL to make things more clear: https://unsafebutsound.com/project/goat/
And here is a screenshot of where I would like them to appear on all project/post pages:
[image]

Comment: This depends on the theme. Its author should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. 
Here is the answer.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack-sharing-butttons-shortcode/#installation
FYI just install and insert Widget block - Shortcode / Gutenberg into post wherever you want and paste the shortcode: [jpshare] into it.
Voila!